# Getting a no package exists error while running a unit test

Tags: corda

I get this error while running my unit test, while initializing the network parameters, this package com.example.contract does exist in my cordapp.

```
 network = MockNetwork(MockNetworkParameters(cordappsForAllNodes = listOf(
                TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.example.contract"),
                TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.example.schema")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There are no CorDapps containing the package com.example.contract on the classpath. Make sure the package name is correct and that the CorDapp is added as a gradle dependency.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `.findCordapp()` In my case the problem was the classpath. I was running the tests in Intellij with the “JAR manifest” option selected for the “shorten command line” option in my Run configurations and that was causing the issue apparently, so instead I selected "none" option and it worked fine. I'm still investigating around this but for the moment I hope this throws some light to your problem so you can go on with your testing.

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/10828717/laura-perez-crespo i am still getting the same error if change it to none.

Comment: if change it to none then it says missing param javaagent

Comment: See the comments once

Answer (score 0):

Please check the intellij **Run/Debug Configurations** if the tests are being run as gradle task rather then a junit one. Since the gradle tasks are the one which can scan the packages for cordapps.

[image]